# Calculate standard error for all variables in survey package

Tags: r, tidyverse, survey

I have a large survey (~250 variables), and would like to generate the estimates and standard errors for all variables, and then share that output with colleagues. It seems as if this should be simple, but up to this point, I cannot find a question similar or an example in the documentation.

My example is from data in `survey` package:

```
data(api)

## one-stage cluster sample
dclus1<-svydesign(id=~dnum, weights=~pw, data=apiclus1, fpc=~fpc)

svytotal(~api00, dclus1, deff = TRUE)
svytotal(~api99, dclus1, deff = TRUE)
```

I know that I can produce the estimate and error for each variable by the above method, or produce a 2-way result below:

```
svytotal(~api00+api99, dclus1, deff = TRUE)
```

however, my goal is to produce the estimate and error for each variable in one step, i.e.

```
svytotal(~(c(pcttest:api.stu)), dclus1, deff = TRUE)
```

so that it returned the estimate and the error for all variables in:

```
apiclus1[, 11:37]
```

Is there a solution through survey package or `srvyr` package?

Comment: maybe `svytotal( as.formula( paste( "~" , paste( names( apiclus1 )[11:37 ] , collapse = "+" ) ) ) , dclus1 , deff = TRUE )`  ?

Comment: thanks for your comment. wasn't quite what I was looking for, but it led me to this response: [lapply and survey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22796372/combining-lapply-svyby-svyratio-to-calculate-many-ratios-with-confidence-inter). I changed it this:   ` lapply( variables , function( z ) svytotal( as.formula( paste0( "~" , z ) ) , dclus1, svytotal , vartype = 'se' ) )`

Answer (score 0):

You currently have a mix of integer and factor columns. You won't be able to calculate standard error over those unless you convert them to numeric first.

In a smaller example, to calculate standard error for multiple columns, you can use `apply` like this:

`apply(apiclus1[,11:15],2,sd,na.rm=TRUE)`

```
   pcttest      api00      api99     target     growth 
  1.686912 105.748867 112.850380   5.247616  29.755257
```

Note that if you change the range to `[,11:16]`, `sch.wide` returns NA because it's a factor and not numeric.

Also, note that your formula for calculating the error `svytotal(~api00, dclus1, deff = TRUE)` returns a non-nonsensical value of `898364` for `api00`.

Comment: Thanks @Mako212, but your answer doesn't use the survey package. The values seem non-sensical because your response doesn't use the weights in apiclus1 in the survey designI recognize the integer and factor columns. You make a good point about the different variable types. Apologies for not being more specific. To be more specific in my question, do you know of a way to produce standard errors and estimates for multiple variables of the same type using the survey package?