# svyby- can you put multiple items in the 'by' part of the function?

Tags: r, list, loops, survey

Just looking for some advice based on a question that has been asked previously ([Combining lapply, svyby, svyratio to calculate many ratios with confidence intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22796372/combining-lapply-svyby-svyratio-to-calculate-many-ratios-with-confidence-inter))

```
variables <- c( "Q_1" , "Q_2", "Q_3" )

lapply( variables , function( z ) svyby( as.formula( paste0( "~" , z ) ) , by = ~gender,
                                         design = srs_design,
                                         FUN = svytotal, na.rm = TRUE,
                                         row.names = FALSE))
```

I have adjusted the code slightly for my purposes but I was wondering if there was a way to create a second list to iterate through in the 'by' statement? I have tried the following but I get an interaction which I do not want.

```
lapply( variables , function( z ) svyby( as.formula( paste0( "~" , z ) ) , by = ~gender + age + location,
                                         design = srs_design,
                                         FUN = svytotal, na.rm = TRUE,
                                         row.names = FALSE))
```

Is there a way to iterate through the 'by' statement as well as the 'variable' statement?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: do you want to pass in two parameters rather than one?  maybe define a function with inputs `y` and `z` -  the function you're using takes only `z`...at the point you define a function with two arguments, you could use `mapply( functionname , var1 , var2 )`

Comment: Is there any way you could show me what that looks like? I'm really stuck with this. Thank you for any help.

Comment: variables <- c( "Q1" , "Q2", "Q3" )
demo <- c("gender", "age", "location")

mapply( variables , demo , function( z, y ) svyby( as.formula( paste0( "~" , z ) ) , by = ~y,
                                                design = srs_design,
                                                FUN = svytotal, ci = FALSE, na.rm = TRUE,
                                                row.names = FALSE))
This is embarrassing but do you mean like this? This does not work!

Comment: with `mapply` the function is the first argument, and `~y` needs a similar `as.formula( paste(`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
svybys<-function(formula,  bys,  design, FUN, ...){

    tms <- attr(terms(bys),"variables")[-1] 
    
    lapply(tms, function(tm){
         eval(bquote(svyby(.(formula),by=~.(tm), design=.(design), FUN=.(FUN), ...)))
    })
    
}
```

With the built-in `api` example I get

```
> svybys(~api00+ell,~stype+sch.wide, dclus1, svymean)
[[1]]
  stype    api00      ell se.api00   se.ell
E     E 648.8681 29.69444 22.36241 1.411617
H     H 618.5714 15.00000 38.02025 5.347065
M     M 631.4400 22.68000 31.60947 2.952862

[[2]]
    sch.wide    api00    ell se.api00   se.ell
No        No 608.0435 23.000 28.98769 4.005597
Yes      Yes 649.3625 28.275 23.42657 1.966037
```

The tricky part of this is that model formulas are a separate sub-language that needs quasiquotation to substitute things.  Here I've used `bquote()`, but you could also have used some combination of exclamation points  and braces and so on with the tidyverse -- you'd want to go via the `srvyr` package for that.